Plot title not centered in ggplot2
I am having a problem getting the title centered relative to the panel in the plot. If I output the plot as a PNG file and inspect the spacing to the left and right of the title with respect to the panel border, they don't seem to be of equal lengths. I'm not sure how to correct this without manually adjustments
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))
ggplot(data = df,aes(x=x,y = y))+
geom_point(color = "yellow")+
theme(
plot.background = element_rect(fill = "black"),
panel.background = element_rect(fill = "black"),
axis.title = element_text(size = 7, face = "bold", colour = "white"),
plot.title = element_text(size = 45, face = "bold", colour = "white"))+
plot.margin = margin(1.5, 1, 1, 1, "cm"),
panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "gray20"),
panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "red", linetype = "solid"),
panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
axis.text = element_text(size = 17, face = "bold", colour = "white"))+
labs(x ="EPIDEMIOLOGICAL WEEK OF 2024", y = NULL)+
theme(legend.box = "vertical",legend.box.just = "center")+
guides(fill = guide_legend(order = 1), color = guide_legend(order = 2))+
theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15,hjust = 0.5,margin = margin(t = 25)))+
theme(rect = element_rect(fill = "black"))+
theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "white", fill = NA, size = 1))+
ggtitle("RSV IN SOUTH AFRICA")+
theme(plot.title.position = "panel")+
theme(
plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
theme(axis.ticks.length=unit(0.1,"inch"))+
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 5)))+
theme(axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(r = 5)))+
theme(axis.text.y.right = element_text(margin = margin(l = 5)))+
theme(axis.ticks = element_line(color = "white"))


theme(plot.title.position = "plot")+ You have this as "panel" which aligns to the center of the plot panel, while it sounds like you want it aligned to the entire figure.

BTW, I think your ggplot2 coding experience will be made much simpler if you can make your code more consistent, so you know where to look for each part, and you avoid repeated lines like plot.title. e.g. I order my ggplot2 calls as ggplot() + geoms + scales + labs + theme, instead of all mixed around.

I wouldn't expect to see the same amount of space to the left of the letter R as to the right of the letter A. Check with a symmetric title, like ggtitle(".__________________.") +


ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(color = "yellow") +
  labs(
    title = "RSV IN SOUTH AFRICA",
    x = "EPIDEMIOLOGICAL WEEK OF 2024", y = NULL
  ) +
  theme(
    rect = element_rect(fill = "black"),
    
    plot.title.position = "plot", ### HERE'S THE LINE TO ADJUST ###
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "black"),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 45, hjust = 0.5, face = "bold", colour = "white"),
    plot.margin = margin(1.5, 1, 1, 1, "cm"),
    
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "black"),
    panel.border = element_rect(colour = "white", fill = NA, size = 1),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "gray20"),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "red", linetype = "solid"),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    
    axis.title = element_text(size = 7, face = "bold", colour = "white"),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15, hjust = 0.5, margin = margin(t = 25)),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 17, face = "bold", colour = "white"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 5)),
    axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(r = 5)),
    axis.text.y.right = element_text(margin = margin(l = 5)),
    axis.ticks = element_line(color = "white"),
    axis.ticks.length = unit(0.1, "inch")
  )

